# Spring: Передать файл через WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, spring, websocket

Я пилю чат, у меня есть старый контроллер:

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/main")
public void add(@RequestParam String letter, @RequestParam(required = false) List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) {
    // Здесь ссылка на файл и текст сообщения сохраняется в БД 
    // Сам файл копируется в локальное хранилище с помощью метода transferTo()
}
```

Но недавно мне понадобилось сделать этот процесс без прерывания TCP соединения. Я наткнулся на WebSocket и написал для него новый контроллер:

```
@ResponseBody
@MessageMapping("/main")
@SendTo("/app/topic")
public String add(@RequestParam String letter, @RequestParam(required = false) List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) {

    return letter;
}
```

Всё ничего, но MultipartFile он принимать не может ибо ругается преобразователь форматов.
Как я могу решить эту проблему, если сейчас у меня вот такой скриптик:

```
let stompClient = null;

function connect() {
const socket = new SockJS('/main');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, frame => {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/chat/main', message => {
        console.log(message.body);
    });
});
}

// Здесь не знаю как конвертировать файл, отправляю только текст
function sendMessage(message){
    stompClient.send("/app/main", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
}
```

И такая формочка

```
            <form id="send-form">
                <textarea type="text" id="msg" placeholder ="Введите сообщение..."></textarea>
                <input type="file" id="partFiles" accept="application/applefile" multiple />
                <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </form>
```

Максимально сократил код, если что-то потерял - требуйте в письменном виде.

Comment: Лучше по websocket-каналу передать URL файла и скачать его отдельным запросом.

Comment: Думал над этим. Мне казалось что так неправильно, пока не прочитал ваше сообщение =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл на фронте в base64(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript) -> передать через сокет -> На бэка из base64 в буфер и сохранить.

Либо на фронте перелючить сокет в режим бинарной передачи -> файл на фронте в буфер -> передать как буфер -> в яве получить и сохранить буфер.